# Как сделать кнопку "Скопировать в буфер обмена" в Python?

Tags: python, tkinter

Если кто-то знает, подскажите, как сделать кнопку "Скопировать в буфер обмена" в Python? Мне надо, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку определённая фраза (например, `ПИТОНИСТ версия 3-8`) копировалась в буфер обмена.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Из примера, я думаю, всё достаточно понятно как, в принципе, это делается.

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
root.clipboard_clear()
root.clipboard_append('ПИТОНИСТ версия 3-8')
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, помогли)

Comment: Ура! Сработало! Ещё раз спасибо)